# DataGridView Removing Rows removes only alternate rows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have 100 rows in a DataGridView. I then remove each row as shown below but as it loops around the ID is coming in as 0,2,4,6,8 and therefore its removing only even rows.  What's going on?

```
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvData.Rows)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (row.IsNewRow)
                            continue;

                        string PalletID = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        string Location = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();


                        dgvData.Rows.Remove(row);
                        AddToList(PalletID + " located in " + Location + " was uploaded");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error Uploading Data");
                        AddToList("Error uploading data " + ex.Message);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe as you loop through the grid and delete the current row, its messing up with the index of the grid which as of now would be causing the rows to shift a level up. So as you proceed further to the next row it has already moved to the index wherein you deleted the row.

Your best bet would be use a for loop and run it reverse and this should work out fine.

Comment: Will give it a go although strangely I have a delete button that does the same loop but it does it over the selectedrows rather than rows and that works fine.

Comment: I think because the `SelectedRows` is totally different collection while in this case you are running over the actual rows of the DataGridView

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you have changed `dgvData.Rows` during the process of loop through it.
I think you need to use `for` instead of `foreach`, if you want to remove items within the loop.

**EDIT** To be more clear:

when you delete the `row` with in the `foreach` loop, the first time it will delete `dgvData.Rows[0]`, and the `dgvData.Rows[1]` will become the new `dgvData.Rows[0]`. So the second time when it delete `dgvData.Rows[1]` it actrully deleted the original `dgvData.Rows[2]`.. etc.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for (int i = dgvData.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    dgvData.Rows.Remove(dgvData.Rows[i]);
}
```

you are using ForEach loop and deleting rows of the same collection, ie dgvData.Rows. That is its missing a object from that collection and failed to loop through each item.
So to handle this you need to loop from behind using the above code.

You need to set the value of i accordingly for the new row if it allows adding new row....

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is possible to me, is that

```
 if (row.IsNewRow)
     continue;
```

let's you skip some rows that have that properties... Try to place there some debug message.

Comment: I've debugged it and its not going through that continue

Comment: So i suppose that every time you delete a row, the "for each" statement messes up with index. Maybe you have to use a while condition with manual index or a for (if you know everytime the number of row in the grid) :)