# How to get the row index of multiple checked in checkbox column of datagridview C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove a all marked/checked rows in an unbound datagridview. The checkbox column was added programatically. I know that I have to use

```
RequestedEmpGrid.Rows.Remove(RequestedEmpGrid.Rows[ForRequestRow.Index]);
```

to remove the row from the grid. However, I am having trouble getting the row index of the multiple checked rows in the datagridview. My looping is not working. Help?

```
                    //REMOVE ALL CHECKED
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow ForRequestRow in RequestedEmpGrid.Rows)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ForRequestRow.Cells[MarkColumn.Name].Value) == true)
                        {
                            RequestedEmpGrid.Rows[ForRequestRow.Index].Selected = true;
                            RequestedEmpGrid.Rows.Remove(RequestedEmpGrid.Rows[ForRequestRow.Index]);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What exacly is not working? Do you get exception, there is no result?

Comment: @user1141604 In which event you need to remove the rows?

Comment: When you are interested in removing rows then its advised that you start from the last row and go deleting one by one else the other way it messes up the index and shouldn't work probably as well as you intend

Comment: So loop to start off from the bottom `for(int indx = rowcount -1; indx=0,i--)`

Comment: Seems very much like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504045/datagridview-removing-rows-removes-only-alternate-rows/6504225#6504225

Comment: @PiotrAuguscik: Only the top of all the checked rows is deleted

Comment: @Nalaka526: Upon remove button click

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try

```
RequestedEmpGrid.Rows.Remove(ForRequestRow)
```

It will just remove the row from gridview but not from Data source, so do not rebind the gridview  as it will add the deleted rows again.

And if you want to delete from datasource as well just delete the selected rows from DB and then rebind the gridview.

Comment: *unbound datagridview* is the key part

Comment: I tried this one, I marked three rows and the bottom two were removed. The first checked row was retained.

Comment: @user1141604 Did you check the link as in my comments that will explain why its failing

Comment: @user1141604 : did you put the debugger to see if you this code gets executed for first row?? I mean were you able to read the checkbox value as true??
Or you can do something like if((CheckBox)ForRequestRow.FindControl("CheckBoxID").Selected)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow requestRow in RequestedEmpGrid.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(requestRow.Cells[MarkColumn.Name].Value))
    {
        RequestedEmpGrid.Rows.Remove(requestRow);
    }
}
```

or this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow requestRow in RequestedEmpGrid.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(requestRow.Cells[MarkColumn.Name].Value))
    {
        RequestedEmpGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(requestRow.Index);
    }
}
```

**update**:
How about that?

```
for (int i = RequestedEmpGrid.Rows.Count; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var row = RequestedEmpGrid.Rows[i];
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[MarkColumn.Name].Value))
    {
        RequestedEmpGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I have tried both codes but not all checked rows are removed. :(